# is there a more efficient way to solve the anagram problem

Tags: c++, anagram

i'm trying to write all the anagram of given number. I did it but is there a more efficient way to solve this problem ? Or How can i do it with letters ?
i'm trying to write all the anagram of given number. I did it but is there a more efficient way to solve this problem ? Or How can i do it with letters ?

Input: 1234

### Output:

1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int digitNumber(int);
bool isAnagram(int ,int  ); 
int reverse(int ); //reverse the number to know where it ends

int main()
{
    int nmbr;
    cin>>nmbr;

    int rev=reverse(nmbr);

    for(int i=0;i+nmbr<=rev;i++)// control the numbers
    {
        if(isAnagram(nmbr,i+nmbr))
        {
            cout<<i+nmbr<<endl;
        }
    }

}

int digitNumber(int number) // number of digit
{
    int digit=0;
    while(number>0)
    {
        digit++;
        number=number/10;
    }

    return digit;
}

bool isAnagram(int number,int number2)
{
    int arr[10]={0};
    int arr2[10]={0};

    int digit=digitNumber(number);
    if(digit!=digitNumber(number2)) //
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while(number>0) 
    {
        arr[number%10]++;
        number=number/10;
    }

    while(number2>0)
    {
        arr2[number2%10]++;
        number2=number2/10;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!=arr2[i])
        {
            return 0;
        } 
    }

    return 1;
}

int reverse(int number) // reverse the number
{
    int result=0;
    while(number>0)
    {
        result+=number%10;
        number=number/10;
        result=result*10;
    }
    return result/10;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you could shorten this up by about 80%+ by utilizing a `std::ostringstream`, a `std::string`, and `std::next_permutation` . [Example here](https://ideone.com/tDVQYv).

Answer (score 2):

Hm, if I understand correctly, you want to print all permutations of a number. The number, or whatever, shall be read from std::cin.

Answer is basically also already given by WhozCraig. All credentials go to him.
I do not want to get downvoted, because I copy and paste from cppreference example code. Give me a comment and I will delete this post. Maybe I am also misunderstanding the question, because it *seems* to be so easy. Also then, please comment, and, I will delete this answer.

The answer was taken from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;  std::cin >> s;
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the output begins with `1243`, you would need to turn your `do { ... } while (...);` into a `while (...) {...}` instead.